# Trying to Create a Folder, but it creates in different location

Tags: asp.net, webforms, directory, creation

In my `ASP.NET WEbForms` app, I want to create a folder and save files in it. In my project I have a folder named `CRMImages/Projects`. I want to create a sub folder in Projects folder & save images from their. Currently I retrieve images from CRMImages/ as the parent folder.

This is my code that I have on code-behind :

```
                try
                {
                    string pathToCreate = "~/CRMImages/Projects/" + item.ProjectId;
                    string myFileName = "";
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate)))
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToCreate);
                        var user = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
                        var userName = user.Translate(typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));
                        System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity sec = di.GetAccessControl();
                        sec.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(userName,
                            System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Modify,
                            System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                        di.SetAccessControl(sec);
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToCreate);

                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("FOLDER CREATED PATH : " + di.FullName);
                        myFileName = pathToCreate + "/projectLogo.png";
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("PATH To Save Logo File & NAME : " + myFileName);

                        /*
                        if (File.Exists(item.ProjectLogoUrl) ) {
                            FileUpload projLogoUpload = new FileUpload();
                            if (projLogoUpload.HasFile) {
                                myFileName = pathToCreate + "/projectLogo.png";
                                projLogoUpload.SaveAs(myFileName);
                            }
                            // panFileBtn.SaveAs(filePath);
                        }  */
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("EXCEPTION While SAving File : " + ex.Message + "\n *** STACK" + ex.StackTrace);
                }
```

The code executes, but I don't see the folder created in my project folder. Lets say the value of item.ProjectId is "EMP3", the logs that I see on the above code execution is :

```
FOLDER CREATED PATH : C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~\CRMImages\Projects\EMP3
PATH To Save Logo File & NAME : ~/CRMImages/Projects/EMP3/projectLogo.png
```

I checked in `IIS Express` folder & there this full path is created. Can you say why is it saving in IISExpress & how to create the folder in the `/CRMImages/Projects` folder that already exists in my project !!

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace below line

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToCreate);
```

With

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(pathToCreate));
```

Comment: Oh Thanks Dexterity for so quick and correct answer. You can see in my above code I have mention Directory.CreateDirectory() 2 times - before and after setting security. As I was getting UnAuthorized Exception so have copied the above code from other site. Is that line required to write twice ??

Comment: Please remove it. no need it twice.

Comment: Then it's better to remove the above one, I think. What do you suggest ?

Comment: Oh no no, the di.SetAccessControl(sec); needs DirectoryInfo that is in the first one !

Comment: I mean next to the di.SetAccessControl(sec); line. Remove Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToCreate); any reason to creating same directory again???

Comment: Thanks alot. One more thing, in the commented code, I am trying to save the file selected by FileUpload as a different name. I mean the file selected is C:\....\Desert.jpg & I want to save it as "projectLogo.jpg" in my created folder. Then is that the right code. I will definetely make SaveAs(Server.MapPath(myFileName)) . But will the code save it as a different name ??

Comment: Yes. That is right but please make sure you use Server.MapPath(pathToCreate) instead of  pathToCreate variable.

Comment: Yes, have made that modification. I am marking this as answer, can you try to have a look at this thread and help me with that also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281037/bind-a-dropdown-in-listview-in-edit-insert-template